# How to handle NullType in Spark Dataframe using Python?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I'm trying to load data from MapR DB into Spark DF.
Then I'm just trying to export the DF to CSV files.
But, I'm getting error is:

> "com.mapr.db.spark.exceptions.SchemaMappingException: Failed to parse a value for data type NullType (current token: STRING)"

I tried couple of ways by casting the column to StringType.
This is one of them:

```py
df = spark.loadFromMapRDB(db_table).select(
F.col('c_002.v_22').cast(T.StringType()).alias('aaa'),
F.col('c_002.v_23').cast(T.StringType()).alias('bbb')
)

print(df.printSchema())
```

Output of PrintSchema:

```
root
 |-- aaa: string (nullable = true)
 |-- bbb: string (nullable = true)
```

Values in column 'aaa' & 'bbb' can be null.
Then I'm trying to export the df to CSV files:

```
df = df.repartition(10)
df.write.csv(csvFile, compression='gzip', mode='overwrite', sep=',', header='true', quoteAll='true')
```

Answer (score 0):

I was getting a samilar issue with a MapR-DB JSON table and I was able to resolve by defining the table schema when loading into a DataFrame:

```
tableSchema = StructType([
    StructField("c_002.v_22", StringType(), True), # True here signifies nullable: https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.1/api/python/pyspark.sql.html?highlight=structfield#pyspark.sql.types.StructField
    StructField("c_002.v_23", StringType(), True),
])

df = spark.loadFromMapRDB(db_table, tableSchema ).select(
F.col('c_002.v_22').alias('aaa'),
F.col('c_002.v_23').alias('bbb')
)
```

Another thing you could try is simply filling the null values with something:
https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.1/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.fillna

```
df = df.na.fill('null')
```